# pip getting installed but pip command giving error

Tags: pip

```
Kishores-MacBook-Pro:~ kishore$ sudo pip
sudo: pip: command not found

Kishores-MacBook-Pro:~ kishore$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1558k  100 1558k    0     0  1466k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1467k
Kishores-MacBook-Pro:~ kishore$ sudo python get-pip.py
```

The directory `/Users/kishore/Library/Caches/pip/http` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The directory `/Users/kishore/Library/Caches/pip` or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages

```
Kishores-MacBook-Pro:~ kishore$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
```

Comment: Try `python3.5 -m pip <whatever>` first; see if that works.

Comment: The `pip` command itself is possibly called `pip3.5`.

Comment: yea it works !! `python -m pip` instead of pip for python 3.5

Comment: And the `pip3.5` command?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
python -m pip
```

General use :

```
python -m pip install <package>
```

`-m` flag is for module-name.